# How can I show Success Message from Backend and display in flex frontend?

Tags: apache-flex, backend

How do I show a success message in frontend after a record is inserted into the backend.
I amm using FLEX as front end and Toad as Backend.

Comment: What do you mean by "Toad" are you using "Oracle"?plz explain. which Service you are using to insert records? i.e HTTPService, Remoting

Comment: @Imran...Toad for SQL Server.....sending data from flex to java eclipse(coding parts which has the procedure for save,fetch records..)..using Toad for SQL SERVER

Comment: @Imran using <mx:RemoteObject............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use remoteObject as in mxml

```
<mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("Back with success");
                Alert.show(event.message.toString());
            }

            private function faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("Back with Error");
                Alert.show(event.message.toString());
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:RemoteObject id="remoteObject" destination="yourdestination"
                            showBusyCursor="true"
                            result="{resultHandler(event)}"
                            fault="{faultHandler( event )}">
    </mx:RemoteObject>
```

Note:Above Code is in Flex3

Hopes that helps

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the front end made a remote call using either RemoteObject, WebService, or HTTPService, each one of those should dispatch a result event when you get a successful result from the server.  I would use the result handler to show the alert.